# Информация о причинах ошибки

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, исключения

Имеется WPF приложение которое время от времени беспричинно  "падает" . При этом винда на экран выводит что-то типа: "прекращена работа программы /programmname/"
Соответственно инфы о том как, что почему и т.п. 0.

Приложение многопоточное, выполняет множество различных действий как по запросу пользователя так и само по себе время от времени. Пишет в файл, читает/пишет в бд, осуществляет работу с сетью и COM портами, вывод на печать и т.д. Использует различные подключаемые библиотеки, в т.ч. неуправляемый код.

Все потенциально проблемные места уже обернуты перехватчиками + подписка на события Unhandledexception приложения и диспетчера. Тотальное логирование так же не позволяет выявить проблемный участок. (только предположения, которые пока не подтвердились) К тому же не удаётся воспроизвести проблему при подключённом отладчике студии.

Вопрос: как выяснить, что приводит к завершению работы программы? Может где-нибудь какой-нибудь системный лог пишется или что-то в этом роде... Получение инфы о том, в какой библиотеке/классе произошла ошибка или причина ошибки ( StackOwerflow, DivisionByZero и т.п.) была бы уже большим плюсом...

Comment: ваше логирование недостаточно тотально, но в принципе да, вы можете порыться в логах  системы. http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13638.troubleshooting-wpf-debugging-wpf.aspx вот эта очевидная статья вами полностью охвачена?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40929/discussion-on-question-by-alexey----).

Answer (score 1):

Обязательно ошибка пишится в EventLog и есть еще утилита от майкрософта с анализом (reliability monitor). Оба инструмента должны помочь.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: "Microsoft рекомендует разработчикам приложений
просто принять политику CLR, предлагаемую по умолчанию. То есть в случае не-
обработанного исключения Windows создает запись в журнале системных событий.
Чтобы просмотреть его, откройте приложение Event Viewer и перейдите к узлу
Windows LogsApplication"

Comment: Дополнительную информацию о проблеме можно получить в приложении Windows Reliability Monitor, запускаемом из панели управления Windows. В нижней части окна приложения, можно увидеть список приложений, закрывшихся из-за необработанных исключений.